# jboss keeps automatically hot deploying/undeploying

Tags: jboss, undeploy

Why does my jboss keeps automatically hot deploying/undeploying my web aplication? I am not changing any code!!

"17:35:23,365 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] undeploy, ctxPath=/Resolucao56"

Comment: I realised that when you edit the pages.xml, a file is created with the name .pages.xml.spdia 

You have to delete this file and all works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that when you edit the pages.xml, a file is created with the name .pages.xml.spdia

You have to delete this file!